# Awesomium Javascript Mouseover event handler

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, awesomium

I want to know how to handle the javascript mouseover event in awesomium.

Every answer are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This link 
http://wiki.awesomium.net/javascript/introduction
explain how to use javascript with awesomium